# Can't receive notification when the app is terminated on Android

Tags: marketing-cloud, android, sfdcmobilesdk-android, mobilepush-android, push-notification

I'm facing an issue

I'm trying to integrate the Salesforce SDK into flutter and create a flutter plugin, so far everything is ok, only on android when the app is closed, I don't receive any notification, since communication between Flutter and native codes are via **MethodChannel** and **binaryMessenger**. So there is no **OnCreate** method in which I config the sdk ( It was mentioned in order to receive notification on background, it's a requirements).

Even I created a CustomFirebaseMessagingService to receive the push messages there, the messages are received there but when the app is terminated I don't get any notification(it's related to the SDK configuration which might be terminated).
If I config and initialize the SDK on this **onMessageReceived**, I get the notifications but the context is differ from the flutter app's context.

```
class CustomMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

override fun onMessageReceived(message: RemoteMessage) {

    if (PushMessageManager.isMarketingCloudPush(message)) {
        SFMCSdk.requestSdk { sdk ->
            sdk.mp {
                it.pushMessageManager.handleMessage(message)
            }
        }
    }
}

override fun onNewToken(token: String) {

    SFMCSdk.requestSdk { sdk ->
        sdk.mp {
            it.pushMessageManager.setPushToken(token)
        }
    }
}
```

Any Idea how to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

In your application's Application#onCreate() you *must* initialize the SDK. Without that, this will never work.

`requestSdk` is an asynchronous callback that is only executed after the SDK has finished initializing. If the application is killed and you receive a push notification, the application *is* launched and you should be initializing the SDK.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, the problem here is flutter is not seemingly associated with native side via an activity, there exist an **MainActivity** which extends **FlutterActivity** and putting the initialization inside **onCreate** doesn't work,
And on the other hand while creating a Flutter plugin to include the SFMC, there exist only an **onAttachedToEngine** method.
I'm trying to implement this in Flutter for the first time, would appreciate if you have any idea about the issue , thanks .

Comment: You need the application class, not an activity.